# Visio-issue with shape name tag

Tags: xml, parsing, visio

I am using 2 circle shapes in visio file.The xml obtained after unzipping contains below information.
 the second tag does not print "Circle" as the shape..I did save the edited file.Also,there are many time issues with actual visio file and unzipped xml file.Some of the xml data is not updated at times.What care should be taken while unzipping

"Shape ID='1' NameU='Circle' Name='Circle' Type='Shape' Master='2'"

"Shape ID='2' Type='Shape' Master='2'"

Comment: Visio has a lot of optional properties.  Each shape in the drawing doesn't need all the properties.  If you are using optional properties make sure they are added to each shape.  You can write a utility to verify that each shape has required properties, then if missing you can alert the users to add the missing properties.

Comment: No,I am talking about general properties not optional properties.Like simple "Name" tag of a shape.As I want to parse this xml file.If I dnt get "Name" of a shape,I wont be able to parse.Secondly,if I use 3 circle shapes.I get "Circle",Circle.2","Circle.3" as the names at times.Any views on this.

Comment: I've seen this issue before in Visio.   We often export Visio drawing to Engineer Cad Tools.  The solution has always been to give a person the list of shapes that were missing properties and have the person manually add the missing properties.  You could write a program to add the missing properties, but managers at my company always took the manual approach.  They felt a program was too risky.

Comment: I should of been clearer in my initial posting.  The properties are optional in Visio, the properties are not optional in the ECAD application that you are using to export the drawings.

Comment: Sorry,but I am not using any ECAD application to export the drawings

Comment: The XML is an export file from Visio drawing.  If the XML is missing properties, then you still have to enter the missing properties back into the Visio drawings just like with the ECAD applications.